# How to count download hit in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I am newbie for Django admin. I have made little site where I am giving option to user to upload some mp3 files.for that I am using Django file upload. I have html page for showing all those files where I have option to download it by clicking on download symbol.
I want to count on every download.
I have added filed in my table to keep it's record.

My html file where I want to count hit.

```
<th scope="row" style="vertical-align: middle;">
     <a href="{{radio_file.audio_file.url}}" download >
     <i class="fas fa-download mr-2 text-danger"></i></a>&nbsp;  
</th>
<td>{{ radio_file.download_count }} </td>
```

- models.py

  class RadioFile(models.Model):
  audio_file = models.FileField(
  upload_to='radio/',
  validators=[validate_file_extension],
  max_length=255,
  help_text="Only wav,mp1,mp2,mp3,m4p,.m5p,wma and voc files are allowed.",
  )

  ```
       category = models.ForeignKey(
           Category,
           related_name='radio_files',
           on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
           null=True,
       )
       trending = models.BooleanField(
           default=False,
           help_text="Tick if you want to show it on Home Page",verbose_name="Feature"
       )
       download_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False,null=False)

       uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(
           settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
           related_name='radio_files',
           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       )
       uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> I have option to download it by clicking on download symbol

So everytime the download is successful write a post request to map item and downloadCount (a field) and increment the downloadCount everytime a download is successful.

Comment: Ranu Vijay thank for replay.
I am doing DownloadCount in views.py with function
def increment_download_count(self):
    """ Increments download_count of an instance by 1"""
    print("Download cout =",self.download_count)
    self.download_count += 1
but I am not able to call it from html file. can you help me?

Comment: this line <a href="{{radio_file.audio_file.url}}" download > must be linked to some views in backend, you can extend you code in this views also.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?